# SkImageDecoder: Factory returned null

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, android-asynctask

I'm using a MySQL server to fetch images from database to android to display in an ImageView. However, I receive the following error:

```
SkImageDecoder:: Factory returned null
```

This has been answered before, but I call `.decodeStream` once? It would be appreciated if you could help me

MainActivty.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
private String imagesJSON;

private static final String JSON_ARRAY ="result";
private static final String IMAGE_URL = "url";

private JSONArray arrayImages= null;

private int TRACK = 0;

private static final String IMAGES_URL = "http://thakurnigamananda.com/getAllImages.php";

private Button buttonFetchImages;
private Button buttonMoveNext;
private Button buttonMovePrevious;
private ImageView imageView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    buttonFetchImages = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFetchImages);
    buttonMoveNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
    buttonMovePrevious = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPrev);
    buttonFetchImages.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonMoveNext.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonMovePrevious.setOnClickListener(this);
}


private void extractJSON(){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(imagesJSON);
        arrayImages = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void showImage(){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = arrayImages.getJSONObject(TRACK);
        getImage(jsonObject.getString(IMAGE_URL));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void moveNext(){
    if(TRACK < arrayImages.length()){
        TRACK++;
        showImage();
    }
}

private void movePrevious(){
    if(TRACK>0){
        TRACK--;
        showImage();
    }
}



private void getAllImages() {
    class GetAllImages extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
        ProgressDialog loading;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Fetching Data...","Please Wait...",true,true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            imagesJSON = s;
            extractJSON();
            showImage();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String uri = params[0];
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(uri);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String json;
                while((json = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
                    sb.append(json+"\n");
                }

                return sb.toString().trim();

            }catch(Exception e){
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    GetAllImages gai = new GetAllImages();
    gai.execute(IMAGES_URL);
}

private void getImage(String urlToImage){
    class GetImage extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap>{
        ProgressDialog loading;
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            URL url = null;
            Bitmap image = null;

            String urlToImage = params[0];
            try {
                url = new URL(urlToImage);
                image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return image;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"Downloading Image...","Please wait...",true,true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
            loading.dismiss();
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
    GetImage gi = new GetImage();
    gi.execute(urlToImage);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == buttonFetchImages) {
        getAllImages();
    }
    if(v == buttonMoveNext){
        moveNext();
    }
    if(v== buttonMovePrevious){
        movePrevious();
    }
}
}
```

Logcat:

```
12-25 22:01:30.150 30009-30009/com.example.ayush.testingfordata     I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : Touch Down
12-25 22:01:30.180 30009-30009/com.example.ayush.testingfordata I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : Touch UP
12-25 22:01:30.340 30009-30225/com.example.ayush.testingfordata D/libc: getaddrinfo called from pid =30009
12-25 22:01:30.340 30009-30225/com.example.ayush.testingfordata E/DataScheduler: isDataSchedulerEnabled():false
12-25 22:01:30.340 30009-30225/com.example.ayush.testingfordata D/libc: getaddrinfo called from pid =30009
12-25 22:01:31.080 30009-30225/com.example.ayush.testingfordata D/libc: dnsproxy getaddrinfo returns 0
12-25 22:01:31.800 30009-30282/com.example.ayush.testingfordata D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
```

Comment: Never mind I fixed, it was an error in PHP scripts.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

fixed, error in PHP scripts and database.